# Why recyclerview returns wrong item?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I try to open video as I click on itemview. Sometimes it works correctly but sometimes it opens the second video when I click first video and vice versa. What I try to achieve is to open first video when I click first recyclerview item and so on.

UserHomeVideoAdapter.java:

```
public class UserHomeVideoAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<FollowList, UserHomeVideoAdapter.UserVideoHolder> {

    Context context;
    final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    String thumbUrl, videoTitle, videoUrl, videoDesc, videoId, publisherId;

    ArrayList<String> videoIdArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public UserHomeVideoAdapter(@NonNull @NotNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<FollowList> options, Context context) {
        super(options);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull UserVideoHolder holder, int position, @NonNull @NotNull FollowList model) {

        Query query = db.collection("Videos").whereEqualTo("publisherId", model.getUserId());

        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(task ->  {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                if (task.getResult() != null) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                        Video video = documentSnapshot.toObject(Video.class);

                        thumbUrl = video.getThumbUrl();
                        videoTitle = video.getVideoTitle();
                        videoUrl = video.getVideoUrl();
                        videoDesc = video.getVideoDesc();
                        videoId = video.getVideoId();
                        publisherId = video.getPublisherId();

                        videoIdArrayList.add(videoId);
                    }

                    if (task.getResult().size() > 0) {
                        db.collection("Users").document(model.getUserId()).get().addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
                            if (documentSnapshot != null) {
                                final User user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);

                                if (user != null) {
                                    if (user.getUserImageUrl() == null) {
                                        holder.userProfileImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
                                    } else {
                                        Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse(user.getUserImageUrl())).into(holder.userProfileImage);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(context, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());

                        Glide.with(context).load(thumbUrl).into(holder.videoImageView);
                        holder.videoTitle.setText(videoTitle);
                        holder.mainContainerVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else if (task.getResult().size() == 0) {
                        holder.mainContainerVideo.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
                        holder.mainContainerVideo.getLayoutParams().width = 0;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(task.getException()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(context, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, VideoActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("videoPublisherUserName", model.getUserName());
            intent.putExtra("thumbUrl", thumbUrl);
            intent.putExtra("videoPublisherEmail", model.getUserEmail());
            intent.putExtra("videoUrl", videoUrl);
            intent.putExtra("videoId", videoIdArrayList.get(position));
            intent.putExtra("videoPublisherFullName", model.getUserFullName());
            intent.putExtra("videoPublisherId", publisherId);
            context.startActivity(intent);

            Log.d("Bax", videoIdArrayList.get(position));
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public UserVideoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.video_cell, parent, false);
        return new UserVideoHolder(v);
    }

    public static class UserVideoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RelativeLayout mainContainerVideo;
        CircleImageView userProfileImage;
        TextView videoTitle;
        ImageView videoImageView;

        public UserVideoHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mainContainerVideo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainContainerVideo);
            userProfileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userProfileImage);
            videoTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoTitle);
            videoImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoImageView);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand the problem with my code so any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How many videos do you have currently in your recyclerview?

Comment: @skafle right now it is 2 but it can change as users upload in the future

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your `videoIdArrayList.add(videoId)` is not being reset. Every time your recyclerview loads, it queries the database and adds `videoId` in the `videoIdArrayList` and that keeps adding.

That is messing up the videoId being sent to the next activity.
So, clear your `videoIdArrayList` Every time the recyclerview loads and add Id's after that.

So, before your for loop in firebase query, just clear the list.
`videoIdArrayList.clear()`

Should work perfectly.

Comment: unfortunately I did what you suggested but got no result. I even tried to clear arraylist in my clicklistener but again no result.

Comment: Yeah... as @anatoli suggested, your query is being executed as many times as number of items your recyclerview is holding at a given time. So it is better idea to transfer your query code to different file and just pass the list to the adapter when you initialize your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

`onBindViewHolder` executes for each item in `RecyclerView`. Not once

`Query query = db.collection("Videos").whereEqualTo("publisherId", model.getUserId());` returns a `List`, not item.

`videoIdArrayList.add(videoId);` could be executed for first item many times.

`String thumbUrl, videoTitle, videoUrl, videoDesc, videoId, publisherId;` are setted in `onBindViewHolder` in Query. Again `onBindViewHolder` executes for each item in `RecyclerView`. Not once.

You must refactor your adapter.

1. execute query over your adapter.
2. It is not clear, what items receive holders. (for me. if for you it is clear -> skip the step)
3. instead `holder.videoTitle` make a method in holder (for example `void configView(YourItem item)`) and evertyhing regarding to that item execute in holder.